# Is this possible - customizing SAP Netweaver endpoint responses

Tags: abap, endpoint, netweaver

I am a consultant building an application for a client. The client is responsible for building the endpoints that my application will consume. The client is using an ABAP-based solution and Netweaver - two pieces of software I don't have any experience with.

The client provides their endpoint responses in both XML and JSON. I've been working with them to improve their endpoints and have run into a lot of issues where they claim what I'm asking for isn't possible. I'm looking for some input - is the client correct or are they underskilled for the job?

Some of my requests:

- Format a date value into a particular format. The client insists that the only format they can have in the response for a date is "/Date(1430502144000+0000)/"
- SAP stores booleans as "X" (true) or "" (false). I asked that the values be converted to "true" or "false" (without quotes) in the endpoint. Apparently this is not possible.
- I have asked that all of details about an item be returned from an endpoint "getItemDetail" - the client insists that to get the item-details I will need to call 5 different endpoints because *"For each array type of response, currently a different call needs to be made. That is the reason for separate end points for arrays for texts, parts etc."*

In general - it seems that the client doesn't know how to build or customize responses and it would seem that their endpoints are 1:1 dumps of their object structures stored in SAP. The idea of "translating" their data seems to be lost to them in SAP. Can anyone confirm/deny the ability to fully customize endpoint responses when using SAP and Netweaver?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure about how SAP can interact with other systems. One I know are webservices. Do you know how is your client generating those XML and JSON?

Comment: My understanding was that this was a capability of SAP Netweaver. Beyond that I'm not sure.

Comment: But if it's a XML, as far as I know, anything can be returned. The 3 of your requests could be acomplished. But, since Im not totally sure, I would recommend toy to wait another comment/answer.

Comment: "SAP NetWeaver" is a marketing term, not an installable product. It comprises a lot of stuff including an ABAP-based application server, a Java-based application server, some MS-based stuff - you name it. What product are we talking about exactly?

Comment: I apologize, but I'm unsure. I spoke with the client today and they were telling me how they have a fully-formed object, but that SAP generates the endpoints based off of that object and for every ARRAY within the object it creates a new endpoint. This sounds like crazy talk to me.

Answer (score 3):

( I can't seem to add comment till I get 50 reputation points )

Hi captian_jim1  ,
 I am working on something similar but from the other end of the table . From SAP , I am generating the XML/JSON output for an endpoint which the external application can consume . So needless to say it is definitely possible. In your particular case you would need to ask your SAP counterpart the following things :

-> Are they using existing web services or creating new custom webservice specific to your requirement ? **If latter then they can re-design and send the required output via just one webservice.** All they would have to do it talk with you and agree on a schema for the data output. From their end, use the existing RFCs/webservices and create the data in SAP for the agreed schema. Once you have the schema , it is straightforward to create an equivalent data structure in  SAP - even complex ones- and get the JSON/XML output for it . I am assuming their netweaver version is not very old and supports XML/JSON transformations.

Comment: They said that they are using "out of the box methods" to create the endpoints. The endpoints are new and didn't exist prior to this project. They are converting their old ERP over to SAP so I assume everything is new.

What you are describing is exactly what I expected to do- work together to form a contract then they implement the contract. The client told me today that they have a "itemDetail" object and they allow SAP to automatically create the endpoints for that object and whenever SAP encounters an array within that object it creates a separate endpoint for that data. Sound familiar?

Comment: Mmm..I am not sure what they mean when they say SAP is automatically creating the end points if they have an 'Item detail object'. Can you check with them the structure of this item detail object and whether that matches with the contract/schema you have in mind ?  In my case I am generating the JSON output as a string and sending it a middleware because that was the requirement. So it is my code which is explicitly creating the JSON/XML output owing to the client requirement/restriction .

Comment: I suspect that what you have done is what they need to do -- that is their code should generate the json. I just found out that they are writing everything in ABAP instead of Java so this could be part of the issue.

Comment: Oh that is no problem. I am generating the JSON/XML output only in ABAP . There is no Java layer involved directly in our set up. You might want to tell them to explore options to generate JSON/XML output from the 'itemDetail' object ( do check that it contains all the information you want ) they have already .

Comment: I've asked, but the claims remain the same. "Any array that's part of the 'itemDetail' object gets it's own endpoint when the endpoints are generated" -- they talk about it like they can't control this behavior. It sounds to me that they don't know what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

All of what you are asking for is possible. However, it's not in your counterpart interest to build an abstraction layer for you. In their world, that is your job. They provide standard services based on standard objects in SAP. That means multiple end-points for almost everything. Generating a standard service is a very minor task and can be done by almost anyone. But building an abstraction layer that fits your application requires a totally different skill set; hence they don't want to do it.

People that understands to design usable services AND the SAP domain model are rare. What you need to work out together with your counterpart is who is responsible for the domain model and then find a developer that can implement and support it. It's the kind of work I do myself. Translating SAP object / domain models to an application-specific API / service-model for non-SAP developers to work with. I work together with UX experts, application developers (web, iOS/Android etc) and functional people with specific SAP knowledge. If you can't form a team like that, I believe you are better off just consuming what they will provide...

Comment: Thank you for the input. It sounds like generating a service from an SAP data-model is done almost with the push of a button. Is it typical SAP behavior to generate a separate endpoint for every field in the data-model that is an array?

Comment: Typically, your average SAP resource will take an inside-out approach. That means finding a suitable "BAPI" or "RFC" that returns the data you are looking for, for example a list of Sales Orders. He will then generate a service based on this interface. He doesn't combine multiple interfaces. See an example of an easy inside-out approach here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YOcfi4MBv0

Answer (score 0):

NetWeaver 7.3 includes [JAXB (ver 2.1) and JAXWS (ver 2.0)](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/49/9bd450070d2221e10000000a42189d/content.htm) (NW 7.1 included ver 2.0 of both). There's no reason their web services cannot return xs:boolean and xs:datetime as long as they are writing an JEE5 web service.